# Webdriver how replace dynamic locator to use Page Factory

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Here is html code:

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a>text1</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>delete<div/>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>
    <a>text1</a>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div>delete<div/>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I need to click on "delete", where  contains specified text (for example "text1").
I do this using following xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/table/tbody/tr/td[text()='" + id + "']/following-sibling::td[3]/div")).click();
```

But I would like to use Page Factory and avoid using dynamic locator.
So does anyone know how to click on needed element in another way?

Answer (score 0):

If your xPath works why can't you use it in page object?

If  you use Java, just do like this:

```
@FindBy(how = How.xpath, using = "".//div/table/tbody/tr/td[text()='" + id + "']/following-sibling::td[3]/div"")
```

Comment: Would this work? I think @Findby captures value at compile time only.